How exactly to prove Thomas precession from Jacson first ed

How exactly prove (11.50) and (11.52) from Lorentz transform ?
$ t'' = t' - \frac{\mathbf{x'}}{c^2} \gamma (\delta \mathbf{v} + (\gamma - 1) \frac{\mathbf{v}\mathbf{\delta v}}{v^2}\mathbf{v})$
$ \mathbf{x''} = \mathbf{x'} + (\gamma - 1)(\mathbf{x'} \times (\frac{\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{\delta v}}{v^2})) - \Delta \mathbf{v} t'$

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14751/200218
